# HashMap get method throwing error on hm.get(hm)

Tags: java, hashmap, stack-overflow

Could you please explain the below scenarios?

```
HashMap<HashMap,HashMap> hm=new HashMap<>();
hm.put(hm,hm);
hm.get(hm); // ----> On commenting this line, I get no error. 
            //       If I uncomment it, I am getting StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Please add the error as well

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.iterator(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractMap.hashCode(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Objects.hashCode(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap$Node.hashCode(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please paste the error and stacktrace (or just a small representative part of it) into the question text and format as code for readability. Don’t expect readers to follow links and look at text as images. Thx.

Comment: You put the hashmap as key and value into itself?

Comment: I am trying to understand why its giving error, on get method.

Comment: “Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key.” [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to put a `HashMap` as a key inside itself is a bad idea.

After `hm.put(hm,hm)`, your `HashMap` contains a key whose `hashCode()` is `hm.hashCode()`. `hm.hashCode()` is a function of the `hashCode()` of all the `Map`'s entries. The `hashCode()` of an entry is a function of the `hashCode()` of the key and value (both are `hm` in your case). Hence, in order to compute `hm.hashCode()`, you have to compute `hm.hashCode()`. This results in infinite recursion.

Calling `hm.get(hm);` required computing `hm.hashCode()`, leading to infinite recursion and `StackOverflowError`.